# Google Docs web publish: wrap lines before end of page?

Tags: google-drive

Is there any way to format a google doc so its published form will not wrap lines to the rightmost extent of the page? For example, consider the following publshed google doc: [MySQL chapter in Michael Borque's PHP Book](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1sQgteKGO6hzx9btrQC553JOJ3IrqpdgcDWRXPj6yRjQ). The lines go from the leftmost portion of the page to the rightmost portion of the page, which is difficult to read. Is there any way to make the lines break before the end of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

Try adding "embedded=true" to the link:

https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1sQgteKGO6hzx9btrQC553JOJ3IrqpdgcDWRXPj6yRjQ&embedded=true

It ends up with double line spacing and it wraps at more or less a well-margined portrait page (16-17 cm)